# Issue with setTimeOut and non-response script in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, settimeout

I am getting an issue with a large amount of processing causing the non-responsive script error in IE8 (and no, I cannot make the users use a better browser).

I then read that it should be possible to split up the tasks and cede control back to the browser in between different parts of the validation.  So I decided to make a simple example based on some code I found to figure out where the breaking points are.  The real code is doing lots of jquery validationengine processing.

I tried to use jsFiddle but I can't get jsFiddle to run in IE8.  Bummer.  So, I'll have to share inline here.

When I first load it, it seems to work just fine.  I push the button and both functions finish without a problem.  However, subsequent pushes causes an unresponsive script error.  I've played around with the number of loops in my simulated work function. Much more than 1.25 million loops and it dies with unresponsive script.

Shouldn't separate calls to the onClick start the non-responsive counter anew?  What am I missing here?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var progress = null;
var goButton = null;

window.onload = function() {
    progress = document.getElementById("progress");
    goButton = document.getElementById("goButton");
}

function runLongScript(){
    // clear status
    progress.value = "";
    goButton.disabled=true;

    var tasks = [function1, function2];

    multistep(tasks,null,function() {goButton.disabled=false;});

}

function function1() {

    var result = 0;

    var i = 1250000;
    for (;i>0; i--) {
        result = result + 1;
    }

    progress.value = progress.value + "f1 end ";
}

function function2() {

    var result = 0;

    var i = 1250000;
    for (;i>0; i--) {
        result = result + 1;
    }

    progress.value = progress.value + "f2 end";
}

function multistep(tasks, args, callback){
    var tasksClone = tasks.slice(0); //clone the array

    setTimeout(function(){

        //execute the next task
        var task = tasksClone.shift();

        task.apply(null, args || []);

        //determine if there's more
        if (tasksClone.length > 0){
            setTimeout(function () {
               multistep(tasksClone, args, callback);
            }, 100);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    }, 100);
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <p><input type="button" id="goButton" onClick="runLongScript();" value="Run Long Script" /></p>
    <input type="text" id="progress" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling `clearTimeout()` to remove the one currently running when the button has been pressed already.  Add an if statement before you start another `setTimeout` and check to see if one is already running, clear it if it is, and then continue.  Here's a link that should help you if you have any questions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout

Comment: I tried that but perhaps I'm not doing it correctly.  It did not seem to help.

Comment: My understanding is that once you call setTimeout() that control is given back to the browser and it resets is notion of the script as being "non-responsive".  That doesnt seem to be happening.